# server side rendering 404 not found on all my images

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am rendering my react app on my server but I get a 404 not found when trying to retrieve images. When I try to go to the directory of my images I get a 404. Why? 404 Not found on `localhost:8000/src/img` this is where my images live.

`server.js`

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './src', '/img')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {

  const error = () => res.status(404).send('404');
  const htmlFilePath = path.join(__dirname, './', 'index.html');
  fs.readFile(htmlFilePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {

    if(err) {
      error()
    } else {
      match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, renderProps) => {

        if(err) {
          error()
        } else if(redirect) {
          res.redirect(302, redirect.pathname + redirect.search);
        } else if(renderProps) {
          const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);
          const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
          const RouterContext = react.createElement(reactRouter.RouterContext, renderProps);
          const provider = react.createElement(Provider, { store: store }, RouterContext);
          const ReactApp = renderToString(provider);
          const RenderedApp = htmlData.replace('{{SSR}}', ReactApp);
          res.status(200).send(ReactApp);
        } else {
          error(); //Always enters this when trying to render images.
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Express docs: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

You may be using the wrong path for your images. It would help to see your HTML, but if you are setting the `src` of your images like `/src/img/my-image.jpg` then that won't work, since the static middleware is relative to the path you give it. You can try `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './src')));` and then use `/img/my-image.jpg` for your images, if you like.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. In my match method it enters the else statement automatically showing an error.

Comment: It's trying to match the req.url to routes, and can't find it, but its not a route, its just an image path.

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is that `redirect` and `renderProps` are `undefined`, so you are dropping through to get the error. And the point still stands; on your machine, images may live in `/src/img` but to express `localhost:8000/src/img` isn't a static path. Unless I'm missing what you are trying to do, in which case please provide all necessary code.